# Pre-caching pages in xamvvm with Xamarin.Forms and ReactiveUI

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

We are currently building a Xamarin.forms iOS and Android app and the MVVM framework we are using xamvvm.

https://github.com/xamvvm/xamvvm/wiki

When we push a page to the stack as a new instance (or for the first time from cache), the page is animated in and displayed before any data binding for dynamic fields and lists take place.

```
ViewModel.PushModalPageFromCacheAsync<MenuPageModel>();
```

This results in the user seeing effectively a broken page during the animation and for short time afterwards until the binding completes.

I was wondering if there is a way of delaying showing the page until the binding has completed, or if there is a way of pre-caching certain pages in xamvvm?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it help if you registered the page upfront? Like described [here](https://github.com/xamvvm/xamvvm/wiki/Bootstrapping-and-Page-Registration)

Comment: I've tried using: `factory.RegisterPage<MenuPageModel>();` but I'll try again and pass a non-default constructor

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't seem to have worked. Perhaps I'll have to do something horrible like Popping and pushing the page whilst the splash screen is on...

Comment: I wonder if it's really if pre caching would help you. Is this problem IOS only?  What you could try is just do a GetPageFromCache before, you push the page. That will create Page and PageModel.